# Vim colorschemes not changing background in Ubuntu terminal

Tags: vim, vimrc

I have the following **.vimrc**:

```
set nocompatible              " Use vim defaults
"set ls=2                      " Always show status line
set showcmd                   " Show incomplete commands
set scrolloff=3               " Keep 3 lines when scrolling
set ruler                     " Show the cursor position all the time
set title                     " Show title in console title bar
set hid                       " Change buffer without saving
set showmatch                 " Show matching bracets

set ts=2                      " Numbers of spaces of tab character
set sw=2                      " Numbers of spaces to (auto)indent
set et                        " Tabs are converted to spaces, use only when required
set sts=2                     " Soft tab stop
set smartindent               " Smart indent
set autoindent
set nocindent
set wrap

set hlsearch                  " Highlight searches
set incsearch                 " Do incremental searching
```

And when I open vim from my Ubuntu 12.04 terminal, I see the colors of the scheme, but the background is the same that the one I open the terminal with. I would say the background should change, but I don't know why it doesn't.

Any help please?

Comment: Why do you think background should change?

Comment: Maybe because [that's what's supposed to happen](http://i.imgur.com/tZutp.png)?

Comment: What colorscheme? Does it have something like `hi Normal ctermbg=something`? What command to load the colorscheme? What's the output of `$ echo $TERM`?

Comment: @romainl I don't understand, he doesn't have any `colorscheme` in his `.vimrc`. why do you say it's supposed to happen?

Comment: If your colorscheme defines a background color you are supposed to see it instead of the terminal's background color. That's why I also ask how he is loading his colorscheme and what it is since I don't see any colorscheme in his vimrc.

Comment: But that's assuming he uses a specific, unnamed colorscheme. Of course, if he is only using the `default` colorscheme he won't see any change because **it doesn't define a background color".

Answer (score 1):

try this to change bg color:

```
:set background=dark
```

or

```
:set background=light
```

to change your color scheme:

```
:colorscheme name
```

Edit colorscheme and set highlight commands, for instance;

```
highlight Normal ctermbg='color'
```

[vivify](http://bytefluent.com/vivify/) is a nice place to get a new color scheme

Comment: `set background=…` does exactly nothing with background. It just tells vim whether it should think that background is dark or light and adjust default colors accordingly. Does nothing for non-default colors (those that are changed by colorscheme). Is altered automatically when colorscheme redefines `Normal` highlighting group. And, by the way `hi Normal ctermbg=color`, no quotes.

Comment: 'color' stands for 'which color do you want'! I have given options to solve the problem! your -1 is excessive!!!

Comment: It is for “try this to change bg color: `set background…`”. It does never change the background. Color is not a problem (not that for -1): it is just uncommon to have `'color'` as a placeholder for things like `Red`. It would be common if you used `ctermbg=color` or `ctermbg={color}`. I now know that `ctermbg='Red'` is accepted as well, but I do not see this acceptance stated in `:h highlight-ctermfg`, only in `:h highlight-guifg`.

Comment: In fact, that line with `hi comment guifg='salmon pink'` is the only line where `:highlight` in help is used with single-quoted arguments (excluding 383’rd patch description in `:h version6`), neither I saw quoting in any colorschemes.

Answer (score 1):

Your `~/.vimrc` doesn't contain any mention of a colorscheme.

That means that either:

- you use the `default` colorscheme, or
- you load a specific as yet unnamed colorscheme manually.

If you use the `default` colorscheme, what you see is **normal**. The `default` colorscheme doesn't define any background color so **you are supposed to see your terminal's background color**.

If you are loading a specific colorscheme, with `:colorscheme colorscheme_name`, and you don't see the background change colors, well… it could be because that colorscheme doesn't define a background color either. See if it contains something like `Hi Normal ctermbg=color`. But we can't debug it because you didn't post it.

I'd bet on the `default` colorscheme.